# Where can I create a branch in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am looking at the repository branches and in the left bar I cannot find the create branch option? Where is this located or do I need to get permission for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the guide "[Branching a Repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branching-a-repository-223217999.html)", but a simple workaround would be to create your branch in a local clone, then push it:

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
git checkout -b newBranch
git push -u origin newBranch
```

The reason you don't see it might be because you are looking at a BitBucket repo you do not own.

Comment: It's more about write permissions than ownership - if you can't write to a repo then you can't create a new branch (or push commits) - but otherwise you're right, the "create a branch" option won't show in the plus-sign menu.

Alternately, OP might be using Bitbucket Server.